My object is stuck in Local VIew
I am having an issue with my mesh being stuck in Local View, I tried removing it and it does that but when I go back to perspective view and re select the mesh again and go into edit mode it does not appear but when I switch back to local view it's still in local view? Any ideas how to fix this? I can upload blend file if need to be. I've tried blender 3.6, 4.1 and 4.2 to see if it made any difference and it did not. I might be doing something wrong?

The file would be helpful. You can use https://blend-exchange.com/

Sounds like you are mixing things up or confusing terms. Local is when you isolate the view to show only objects which were selected while entering local view with either / (# on German keyboard) or Numpad /, this view can be Perspective or Orthographic just as the regular non-isolated view as well. If a mesh disappears when switching from Object Mode to Edit Mode this usually means you've probably hidden the mesh with H, press Alt+H to unhide it. Although a hidden mesh does not reappear when going into Local. We need your file or at the very least screenshots.

I ended up deleting it and re-making a new one, I probably missed the hide feature or didn't think of it at the time. I've fooled with it for about an hour I got frustrated. I just gave up and told myself just make a new one. Thank you for replying back with me though!
